# Windows 10 import pem file for openssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, windows-10, openssh, pem

Windows 10 Pro

OpenSSH client is already installed.

I have a pem file supplied by my AWS EC2 instance.

How and where do I install the pem cert in Windows 10.

mmc doesn't recognize the format.

This is the ssh command I want to run.

ssh -i c:\my.pem ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xxx.

As expected I get `WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE ... ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xxx: Permission denied`
but this shows the OpenSSH client is working.

I've searched the internet and SO to no avail .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See ibug's answer here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open

"You locate the file in Windows Explorer, right-click on it then select "Properties". Navigate to the "Security" tab and click "Advanced".

Change the owner to you, disable inheritance and delete all permissions. Then grant yourself "Full control" and save the permissions. Now SSH won't complain about file permission too open anymore.

It should end up looking like this:

[image]"

Answer (score 2):

I kept my pem files in this location

```
C:\Users\<user name>\.ssh\pems
```

And from user folder, that is `C:\Users\user name>,` used this command.

```
ssh -i ".ssh\pems\key.txt" centos@XXX.XX.110.1X5
```